# How can I print the time of an error in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I've seen some errors going through my console but it does not show who made the error, or what time the errors occurred. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please show your code. Use `try catch` and `datetime` for showing timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datetime module is useful for that

```py
from datetime import datetime

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    print(f"{datetime.now()} - {ctx.author}: {error}") # You can also use the utcnow method
    raise error
```

Sample output

```
2021-02-03 14:35:08.508341 - user#1111: some error here
```

EDIT:

Dispaying time in EST timezones

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # built-in, no need to install

timestamp = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('EST'))
```

Another option is to subtrack the 5 hour difference from the UTC time

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

timestamp = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=5)
```

Comment: Is there a way to print it in EST rather than UTC?

Comment: It's kind of off-topic from your question, but I edited my answer